# Should answers which add unspecified effects be downvoted?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

So I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967878/string-tokenizing-from-textview/20967954?noredirect=1#comment31500753_20967954) in which the user wanted to tokenize a phrase and place it elsewhere.  I also down voted an answer which effectively modified the phrase by not replacing the original spacing between words.  The user seems to have taken this personally and claimed I was outwith Stack Overflow guidelines.

So, was it wrong of both of us to assume the users intended final result?  If so is the only way to answer a question with a small amount of vagueness to try cover all bases or not answer until this vagueness has been resolved, even if the question can mostly be answered?

Comment: I've noticed the user has now removed their answer.  My question still applies though

Comment: Your votes are your own, you can use them as you see fit as long as you don't target a specific user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Whether you were right to vote

As always: you can vote as you see fit so long as it does not constitute voting fraud (basically voting for a person rather than the post or voting to give yourself an unfair advantage). So right there you're good.

It's also usual to downvote answers which are in your opinion wrong, this sounds like in your opinion the answer was wrong. So again you're fine here, if other people disagree they will vote differently.

### My personal (and irrelevant) opinion

Personally when I see tokenisation, I don't expect the token to end up in the data (when importing comma delimited data to Excel you don't see a stray comma at the end of the data), but that's just my opinion and shouldn't affect your voting at all.

Comment: I assumed replacement of the tokens only because it was a written word phrase and without the tokens it looses meaning. Personal opinion could be confusing in an answer however so I've extended my answer to reflect this.  Thanks :)

Comment: @BillWoodger That may be it, I was grace editing a lot in the first 5 minutes